# Spring MVC 4 java config does not recognize internationalization change

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

this is my project structure:

[image: Project structure]

these are all classes of my sample to use spring i18n internationalization, but spring only use en_US for application localization:

**SpringWebInitializer**

```
public class SpringWebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(SpringWebConfig.class);

        rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }
}
```

**SpringWebConfig**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.rgh.web")
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("fa"));
        localeResolver.setCookieName("lang");
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <spring:message code="app.name" />
    ${pageContext.response.locale}
</body>
</html>
```

**messages_fa.properties**

app.name=MyAppFarsi

**messages.properties**

app.name=MyApp

Comment: Remove the `RequestContextListener` and then I guess your `index.jsp` breaks. Why because the `index.jsp` isn't served through spring but directly hence the spring localization has no way of kicking in .

Comment: i removed RequestContextListener, but internationalization doesn't work again.

Comment: Where is your `index.jsp` situated?

Comment: as you seen in project structure image it's located under webapp folder

Comment: Move it and let spring handle it. It is now processed by the normal container instead of through spring. Create a view controller for the `/` path and make it return a view name which you put in your view directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help, is there a way to use internationalization without having `Controller` and `ModelAndView`?

Comment: As stated registered a [view-controller}(http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-view-controller). Underneath it does the same but you don't need to write anything for it.

Comment: how can i using internationailization by removing `viewResolver` bean and want to navigate thorough the pages by `<c:url />`,

Comment: If you don't want to use spring then don't use spring... Either use it and work with it don't try to work around it.